# Can we use Apache Sling for Production serving a website directly without any other web server?

Tags: sling

We are developing a website using Apache Sling API. The site works good on `localhost:8080`. Can we change have our website served from directly from Sling instead of any middle web servers (like Apache)?

Can we change the host name in `Apache Felix Http Based Http Service` from `0.0.0.0` to `www.domain.com` ?

Is this possible?
 `www.domain.com --> Apache Sling --> Linux VM`

Comment: You can, but Sling's request processing and the numerous apis that make it so versatile also make it slow and vulnerable to attacks. this is primarily why a dispatcher is needed.

Comment: Thanks. Can we also just use Apache without Dispatcher for multiple domains, something like this `www.domain.com --> Apache --> Apache Sling --> Linux VM` ? We do not want to use with Adobe/AEM related products.

Comment: in principle, it could be done that way. But I don't know any open source solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can. But as the commenters have pointed out, it's probably not a secure solution. We do not have our our production-readiness checklist, but you might want to study the [AEM Security checklist](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/administering/using/security-checklist.html), as many items apply to it.

Pay special attention to items such as:

- Change Default Passwords For the AEM and OSGi Console Admin Accounts
- Protect against Cross-Site Request Forgery

Unfortunately many of the items present under the dispatcher checklist are not applicable, since the dispatcher is only available to AEM customers. However, at a minimum I would suggest that you block access to

- the web console
- composum (if deployed)
- the DavEx Servlet